# Invalid argument error using send button

Tags: javascript

When I click an embedded SendButton I obtain the error "Invalid Argument" that occurs in the following code statement:"a.width(b.style.width+'px');". It is happening in InternetExplorer9.
How can I fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Oh dear... thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Please improve your question so it can actually be worked on and answered.

Comment: This error occurs when the process execute the following code statement: "a.width(b.style.width+'px');". This error only happens using Internet Explorer9

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these two:

```
a.width((0 + b.style.width) +'px');

a.width(parseInt(b.style.width) +'px');
```

Otherwise, make sure "b" is an object, it has style info attached, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I can´t modify the javascript page code because it is generated by facebook.com for the SendButton. I embedded this button using this code generated by facebook: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=139700726163936";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 
</script>

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then, unfortunately.  It's great you came here for help as this is arguably the best place for help, but in order to get more positive, constructive feedback, please, please... read the FAQ to get a better idea of how to form questions and responses.

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding and mistakes. It's my first time triyng to ask a question in this forum and also, I speak other languaje. Can I post again my question improving my explanation?